# Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: class, find, load

When I run my program this says:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Hello world

Every setting I did several times but I get the same result. 
Win 8.1 64 bit 
Path settings ok
eclipse jre setting ok

```
public class newproject1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World! ");
    }
}
```

---

> Error: Could not find or load main class newproject1

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your code please? It's hard to say what's up with your code without being able to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that your Hello world class does not have a main method defined. The format is:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //in here you put what you want the program to do
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I just got "Error: Could not find or load main class" in Eclipse indigo. I don't know if your problem is the same or not. In my case my project code  was a backup of the original and I named the backup folder  as "x86 31 mayıs yedek".  "mayıs" is  turkish word and there are generally problems associated with turkish characters and their language settings in software.  "ı" in the this word is  special character in turkish language.

Simply, I removed the project from the eclipse, I changed the backup folder's name by removing any extra character which is not in english. Then I imported the project again, rebuild it and It worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after trying some different ways, finally solve my problem by setting again the workspace!

File-> Switch workspace-> other

and set it again!